# fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

when I try to import GLFW I get an error in VSCode saying "fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory". I read some articles about this error but could not understand how to solve this issue. Thank you for your help!

Project structure:

```
src/
   main.c
lib/
   GLFW/
       include/
              GLFW/
                  glfw3.h
       glfw3.lib
```

Here is my main.c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h> // fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!");

    return 0;
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\**",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\lib\\**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Since you use double-asterisk `**` in the include path `"${workspaceFolder}\\lib\\**"`, doesn't that mean that the `lib/GLFW/include/GLFW` directory is added? So you need to do `#include <glfw3.h>`?

Comment: Hi, I tried but just got the same error: "fatal error: glfw3.h: No such file or directory"

Comment: I don't know VSCode very well, but perhaps `workspaceFolder` is not possible to use in the C and C++ configuration file? Perhaps it needs to be used only in the `tasks.json`? Like adding to `args`: `"-I${workspaceFolder}\\lib\\GLFW\\include"`?

Answer (score -1):

c_cpp_properties.json

```
    "forcedInclude": [
        "C:/VulkanSDK/1.3.204.1/Include/vulkan/vulkan.h",
        "C:/glfw-3.3.6.bin.WIN64/include/GLFW/glfw3.h"
    ]


    "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/include",
        "C:/VulkanSDK/1.3.204.1/Include/**",
        "C:/glfw-3.3.6.bin.WIN64/include/**",
        "C:/glm"
    ]
```

Comment: I think using absolute paths is not the way to solve the problem, neithe using "forcedInclude".

Comment: You think this is not the way to solve the problem but the reality is different. I solved this problem using forcedInclude for my own project that I started before I follow a Vulkan tutorial. This definitely solves the problem. You wrote comment without testing it.